# Hopf bifurcation how to prove

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have this system of differential equations:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=1-(b+1)x+x^2 y\\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}=bx-x^2 y
\end{equation}

I now that we will have a bifurcation when $b$ grows and passes $2$ and we know that the stationary point is $(1,b)$.

I know that we need to change the variables in our systems to our new variables $u = x - 1$ and $v = y - b$

I understand that it will be three conditions:

non-hyperbolicity condition: conjugate pair of imaginary eigenvalues)
transversality condition: the eigenvalues cross the imaginary axis with non-zero speed
genericity condition

Can you help med attack this problem?

Comment: start by changing variables and write here what you get...

Comment: dv/dt=bu-u^2 v-u^2 b-2uv-2ub-v and du/dt=u(b-1+uv+ub+2v)+v